# From UserControl page, Call Page_Prerender in Parent page

Tags: c#, user-controls, parent, prerender

I have a aspx page name MakeRedemption.aspx, in which have a UserControl (Search.ascx).

There is Page_Prerender() in the MakeRedemption.aspx.

I would like to ask, how can I call the Page_Prerender() from MakeRedemption.aspx, by a function in Search.ascx.

It is something as follow :

Actually there is a looping in one of the function in my User Control page.

The Page_Prerender (MakeRedemption.aspx) will trigger after all the loop finish.

What I want is : 
Everytime before end of each itme of the loop, I will like to trigger the Page_Prerender on the MakeRedemption.aspx to do something.
Something like :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++)
{
//some code here

// I would like to trigger Page_Prerender here to do something before end of the loop.
}  // the Page_Prerender (in MakeRedemption.aspx) trigger after all the loop finish.
```

Means that, this for loop has i = 10, thus, I would like to trigger the Page_Prerender 10 times inside the for loop.

My PreRender function in the aspx file is as follow :

```
protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code here
    }
```

Not sure this Page_Prerender() is consider as the auto generate OnPreRender() or not.

I would like to trigger this Page_Prerender() instead of OnPreRender() .

Sorry if I am asking a stupid question, I am new in programming and c#.

Kindly advise.

Thanks.

Comment: So let me get this straight you want to have a child control (Search.ascx) call its parent (MakeRedemption.aspx) 10 times, once on each loop iteration? To do what exactly? I am confused as to what the parent page would need to do 10 times from a search control. It is generally a poor design choice to invoke parts of the ASP.NET page life cycle from within a child control, but I am curious as to why you feel the need to do it.

Comment: Thanks Karl. Actually, there is a AddCart() function in the Search.ascx, when i run this system in debug mode, i found that, every time after finish run the AddCart(), it will run the Page_Prerender() also. But this is in case the i = 1. Now I would like to change the i, maybe 10 or maybe other number, but the Page_Prerender() will only run after the last i. What I want want is trigger the Page_Prerender() each time of the i. 
Kindly let me know if my question have problem.  : )

Comment: What is the relationship between AddCart() and the Page_PreRender(), logic-wise? Does the Page_PreRender() update a UI element that shows another item in the cart?

Comment: Hi Karl. Actually I am enhance other people project, and this project developer no longer here, so i have no once to ask. As my understading on the code, there is no relationship between AddCart() and the Page_PreRender(), what I guess is, when AddCart() is the final code to run in user control page (Search.ascx), then it will automatic trigger the Page_PreRender() in the parent page (MakeRedemption.aspx). Now if I just call the AddCart() in the for loop, all the user input data will be same as the last i, althought i key in different data every i (pop up window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the way to do it, the oodng is as follow :
Add this following code in the aspx.cs page:

```
delegate void DelMethodWithoutParam();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DelMethodWithoutParam delParam = new DelMethodWithoutParam(Page_prerender);
        this.ucSearchGifts.PageMethodWithNoParamRef = delParam;
    }
Page_prerender(){
//some code here...
```

}

and add this following code in the user control cs page:

```
private System.Delegate _delNoParam;
    public Delegate PageMethodWithNoParamRef
    {
        set { _delNoParam = value; }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _delNoParam.DynamicInvoke();
    }
```

When click on the Button1 in user control page, the Page_prerender() in aspx page, which is parent page, will be trigger.