# Can I change div id from c# code behind

Tags: c#, html, code-behind

I have a division something like :

```
<div id="divAdditionalInfo" runat="server">
//html code here
</div>
```

In code behind, I need to prompt out a small window (generate by this div) more than 1 time.

Because it is the same div, so I only can see the final time window pop up.

My main question is, Can I change the div id in code behind? 
and then use the div id to pop up another window.

Something like :

```
divAdditionalInfo.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
divAdditionalInfo.Style["display"] = "table-cell";
```

After change :

```
divAdditionalInfo.ID = "div2";
```

But I cant write code like :

```
div2.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
```

I only can write back :

```
divAdditionalInfo.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
```

There is find control method for panel, text box, button and so on, but how about division?
Can find control division?
something like :

```
Division d = (Division).FindControl("div2"); //find control on the div id that just change

    d.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
```

kindly comment my question is not clear : )

Comment: I have try to change other element such like text box, lable, button, add thier class, or some attributes. But not sure how to change the division id.

Comment: So how did you change that IDs.?

Comment: `div1.ID = "div2"; lbl1.Text = lbl1.Text + div1.ID.ToString();` I have tried this but it works only until the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried something like this.
aspx file:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Div ID: "></asp:Label>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btn_change" runat="server" Text="Change" OnClick="btn_change_Click" />
```

On button Click event:

```
div1.ID = "div2";
lbl1.Text = lbl1.Text + div1.ID.ToString();
```

It will change the ID of div for the *temporary*. Button when you refresh the page it will automatically get the ID which you have specified on ASPX page.

I think this will work when the ID is chenged by you at that time you can perform the operations you want to perform.

***You will able to find Div Tag in FindControl() of panel or form but in Code behind You will not have the Division Control or something like that. Because it not the Asp.Net control it is typical HTML control.***

Comment: Thanks Rahul Gokani, what you provide here is correct : )
But I think i asking wrong question, I already edit my question, kindly have a look and advice : )

Comment: You can try by having <form> tag or something like. I have form tag in my page I have <form> and I use its FindControl method and i am able to find that control.

Comment: But you will not able to find <Div> in that. Because it not the Asp.Net control. You will only able to find the .Net controls in your code Behind.

Comment: Hi, you means find control of division? or form?

Comment: Is there any way like after I change `divAdditionalInfo` to `div1`, 
then I can write code like `div1.Style["visibility"] = "visible";` ?

Comment: I don't think so. I have also searched for the same. but was not able to find any thing regard this. And i Mean to say `form1.FindControl()`. You will not be able to get Div tag because It is typical HTML tag.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me in another question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139714/from-usercontrol-page-call-page-prerender-in-parent-page